# Change select options to list or grid view

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I want change select options to grid view.

I mean for now I must select an option to view the title, picture and buttons as you look here https://www.screencast.com/t/db7mGdlNgz

```html
<div class="import-form-fields">
  <select class="demo_version" name="demo_version">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <?php foreach ($list as $key => $value): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" data-imported="<?php echo ($this->is_version_imported( $key )) ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value['title'] ); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Also i want that all options are showing in 1 time without select option.

**How can i do this ? Please help me.**

Comment: What do you mean by _"change select options to grid view"_? The image you posted is just showing a select box, some images and a button. I fail to see the relevance. You need to show us what you've tried, the expected result and what result you're currently getting. Right now, your question is _very_ unclear.

Comment: @SarvanKumar - When editing a question, it's OK to reformat the OP's code for readability but don't change or add elements to it.

Comment: this is the result that i have for now https://www.screencast.com/t/jcwZWtjD7w  also i want to see  all the options withawt click on the select dropdown i want to get somthing similar to this https://i.imgur.com/kHQ65rJ.png ..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to show all the options are to create a pseudo elements in Javascript.

or if you allow multiple select, you can list them all at once too.

```
<select multiple>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,   the select multiple is a good idea , but i don't want to use the select because it give almost the same as you look here https://i.imgur.com/LWtxiNH.png , i want only to show all options at once , how can i do this with javascript ?

Comment: you're welcome. you should test out <input type="radio" id="radioButton" value="test">test</input>

Comment: this is not working , also i want to see all the options withawt click on the select dropdown i want to get somthing similar to this i.imgur.com/kHQ65rJ.png ..